# Traefik 2.0 and docker simple configuration doesnt work

Tags: docker, traefik

I'm following some tutorial [link_to_tutorial](https://containo.us/blog/traefik-2-0-docker-101-fc2893944b9d/) about traefik 2.0 and docker, and I have docker-compose file which starts up two containers: traefik and my-app. The problem is when containers up and running, I am not able to browse to localhost:8082, as suggested by configuration, I always get "unable to connect" in browser.

docker-compose.yml :

```
version: "3.3"

services:
  traefik:
    image: "traefik:v2.0.1"
    command:
      - --entrypoints.web.address=:80
      - --providers.docker
      - --api.insecure
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "8080:8080"
    volumes:
      - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro"

  my-app:
    image: containous/whoami:v1.3.0
    command:
      # It tells whoami to start listening on 8082 instead of 80
      - --port=8082
    labels:
      - "traefik.http.routers.my-app.rule=Host(`whoami.docker.localhost`)"
      - "traefik.http.services.my-app.loadbalancer.server.port=8082"
```

However I am able to get localhost:8080 and traefik UI works well. As I understand all requests to "traefik" container normally should be redirected to "my-app":8082 container but it somehow fails. Help heeded.Thanks.

Comment: Exactly how are you making the request? You have a hostname-based rule, which means you would have to either accessing the service at the url `http://whoami.docker.localhost` or you would need to be explicitly setting the `Host:` header.

Comment: I am making  http://localhost:80' and it gives "page not found", but when Im making http://whoami.docker.localhost , as you said, it works. So Im little confused about where to put Host: header in this case? Thanks.

Comment: Thank you very much, everything works as expected!

Answer (score 1):

"traefik.http.routers.my-app.rule=Host(`localhost`,`127.0.0.1`)"